# Weird behavior of jquery click event handler with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

**Hi everybody,**

I am building an application which includes a fast interval along with a scrollTop modification. I have an overflowed div and each interval cycle update's the scrollTop position of that div. I run into a very weird behavior of the click event handler which does not fire.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="cube red"></div>
    <div class="cube gray"></div>
    <div class="cube blue"></div>
    <div class="cube green"></div>
    <div class="cube orange"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {border:0px; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#wrapper {width:350px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;}
#wrapper .cube {width:350px; height:100px; float:left;}

.red {background-color:#f00;}
.gray {background-color:#454545;}
.blue {background-color:#1d5ef3;}
.green {background-color:#0c0;}
.orange {background-color:#f60;}
```

Javascript:

```
var myInterval;
var i = 1;
var el = $('#wrapper');
var cubeNum = ('.cube').length;

el.click(function(){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
});

myInterval = setInterval(function(){
    el.scrollTop(i * 100);
    i++;
    if(i >= cubeNum)
        i = 0;
},16.6);
```

You can see here a simple example of the bug:
http://jsfiddle.net/rMN55/

You can notice that the click handler is not fired from the first click.
If you raise the interval to 300ms than everything works fine.

Another thing that I noticed is that if I changes the handler to mousedown (With the same 16.6 ms interval) than everything works as it should.

Javascript:

```
var myInterval;
var i = 1;
var el = $('#wrapper');
var cubeNum = ('.cube').length;

el.mousedown(function(){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
});

myInterval = setInterval(function(){
    el.scrollTop(i * 100);
    i++;
    if(i >= cubeNum)
        i = 0;
},16.6);
```

Check out the same example with a mousedown handler attached:
http://jsfiddle.net/rMN55/1/

Is this a bug in the way that jQuery handles clicks? 
Should i open a ticket in the bug report system?

Comment: Looks interesting indeed. It seems that changes to scrollTop somehow influence the firing of the click handler. `onmousedown` works differently probably because it fires **while** the mouse click is held over an element - which comes into play the moment the next rendering keyframe has been reached (assumptions, purely, these are).

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with jQuery.

Comment: I bet it's because the "mousedown" event happens over a different target than the "mouseup", so there's no "click" synthesized.

Comment: A click has to fire the mousedown and mouseup event on the same element, if that doesn't happen, there was no click. Changing the position the elements move, and the click never happens because the mousedown and mouseup events took place on two different elements.

Comment: @adeneo yes, exactly - if the timer is slowed down and you hold the mouse button down across a color change, it also doesn't work.

Comment: Also OP I think browsers will ignore the fractional part of your milliseconds argument.

Comment: Should be easy to test, two elements, mousedown on the first, move the cursor, mouseup on the second, doesn't fire a click on the parent element as the events bubble from two different elements -> http://jsfiddle.net/z9vrX/

Comment: I know that a click consists of mousedown + mouseup combined, but I attach the event to a single wrapper. Why it is affected by the nested childs? event bubbling should on go up in the DOM, isn't it?